# How to do offline maps in android?

Tags: android

I want to develop an application with the use of offline map,But i have no any idea for doing the same, can anybody explain me how to integrate offline map in android for a particular country?

Comment: you can not do like this, and please post your research or code with asking the question here

Comment: I have done researchs. What i am unable to get is from where can i get Basemaps for free?. and my main concern was using vector display not a raster one like google making it slow. Thanks Kirti

Comment: ok then please mentioned in your question so that others also can use it

Comment: I cannot find any sources for viewing maps in vector display mode that's why i came here. All are in raster display mode which generally require more memory. i am about to finish my project in raster display but eventually the offline basemaps provider's link no more works. All i want to do is to make it work in vector display mode too. thanks btw ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the option of using [OpenStreet Map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) via [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid).

> osmdroid is a (almost) full/free replacement for Android's MapView (v1
>   API) class. It also includes a modular tile provider system with
>   support for numerous online and offline tile sources and overlay
>   support with built-in overlays for plotting icons, tracking location,
>   and drawing shapes.

Comment: Thanks. But do it provide offline maps for downloading?

Comment: @Bishal Search "openstreetmap data download".

Comment: Thanks @aleung and Little child... i will let you know more later.

Comment: @aleung i was looking for mapsforge i guess now. can you show me any idea of using it with maven?